# Posting variables with Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I use my code to upload data in MySQL.

```
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL_POST_TIENDAS);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", json));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        // Log.e(TAG, "Ejecutando POST: Mandando tiendas");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httppost);
        if (httpResponse != null) {
            int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    message = NetworkUtils.Entity2String(httpResponse);
                    Log.e(TAG, "Respuesta del Post Tienda:" + message);
                }
            } else {
                Err error = new Err(statusCode, message, "upload_tiendas");
                MyApplication.lErrors.add(error);                   
                this.cancel(true);
            }
```

This code give me a 500 Error

In PHP, I receive my variable with $_REQUEST, so when I debug my app, copy json variable and put it in the full URL, there is no problem.

This show my json variable is OK, as URL_POST_TIENDAS.

Why is there a problem with using POST??? This is not the first time I find this problem.
I always change it to GET, but this time, I want to understand why it fails, because I could have a lot of information to upload, so GET is not very appropriated!

EDIT : When seeing logs server, I don't see anything about my 500 error.

EDIT2: httpost :

```
httppost    HttpPost  (id=830032727152) 
aborted false   
abortLock   ReentrantLock  (id=830032727328)    
connRequest null    
entity  UrlEncodedFormEntity  (id=830032731528) 
    chunked false   
    content (id=830032746160)   
        [0...99]    
        [100...199] 
        [200...299] 
        [300...399] 
        [400...499] 
        [500...599] 
        [600...699] 
        [700...724] 
    contentEncoding null    
    contentType BasicHeader  (id=830032747320)  
headergroup HeaderGroup  (id=830032727200)  
    headers ArrayList  (id=830032727216)    
        array   Object[16]  (id=830032727240)   
        modCount    0   
        size    0   
params  BasicHttpParams  (id=830032789608)  
    parameters  null    
releaseTrigger  SingleClientConnManager$ConnAdapter  (id=830032798576)  
uri URI  (id=830032727376)
```

Any Help will be appreciated !

Comment: What do you actually receive on server side? You must be receiving something as the error 500 comes from the PHP server.

Comment: I checked the logs, and nothing appears...

Comment: I wasn't thinking about the logs but about the actual request. What do you see if you just `<?php echo $_POST; ?>` ?

Comment: it seems that $_POST['data'] is NULL... but why????

Comment: I confirm in the line :    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", json));
 json is not null

Comment: If nothing is received, nothing is received. There is a reason. Have you inspected the httppost entity?

Comment: I'm inspecting it, but I don't know which parameter check! I will update my question with that info :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set content type in your httpPost

```
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

## Update

Here is the blog which is doing the same thing.

[Send data as json from android to a PHP server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php)

Comment: Nop, still have the problem.

Comment: I think you should follow the link above

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$_POST` array instead of `$_REQUEST` when you are using *POST* method for sending params.

I think this will resolve your problem.

Comment: I use $_REQUEST to test with GET. When Bug resolved, I will use POST